# sylius controller customization is not overriding the vendor controller

Tags: controller, sylius

i had done all the process as described in the official document of Sylius controller customization(http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/customization/controller.html). But the controller defined is not overriding the default standard controller.

```
services:
    sylius.controller.shop.homepage: AppBundle\Controller\Shop\HomepageController
```

It reports an error from the service as

> A service definition must be an array or a string starting with "@" but string found for service "sylius.controller.shop.homepage" in /home/xxxx/web/rude_data/app/config/services.yml. Check your YAML syntax in /home/xxxx/web/rude_data/app/config/services.yml (which is being imported from "/home/xxxx/web/rude_data/app/config/config.yml").

I am new to sylius,

so some tutorial would be better. Thank u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be:

```
sylius.controller.shop.homepage:
        class: AppBundle\Controller\Shop\HomepageController
```

And I would advice you to join the sylius slack channel, there you can ask for questions about documentation and sylius related problems. The community is really helpful :)

Comment: Thank you for the response. That was really helpful. The controller has been overridden.But i still got the problem. Here is the error.              
             " Type error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Controller\Shop\HomepageController::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\EngineInterface, none given."